# How can I automatically time commands in bash?

Tags: bash, time-command

In `tcsh`, there's the variable `time`:

```
   The time shell variable can be set to execute the time builtin command
   after the completion of any process that takes more than a given number
   of CPU seconds.
```

How do I do this in `bash`?

Answer (score 16):

I don't think you can achieve exactly the same effect without modifying the bash source. But you can get close, hopefully close enough for you.

You can combine [bash's hacky precommand hook](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) and the `SECONDS` variable to show the wall clock time in a non-intrusive way. Here's a simple implementation due to [Ville Laurikari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862510/how-can-the-last-commands-wall-time-be-put-in-the-bash-prompt/1862762#1862762). The functions `timer_start` and `timer_stop` are executed immediately before starting a command and immediately before displaying the next prompt.

```
function timer_start {
  timer=${timer:-$SECONDS}
}
function timer_stop {
  timer_show=$(($SECONDS - $timer))
  unset timer
}
trap 'timer_start' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND=timer_stop
PS1='[last: ${timer_show}s][\w]$ '
```

To get the full `time` information for every command, here's a way due to [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176386/automatically-timing-every-executed-command-and-show-in-bash-prompt/1177511#1177511):

```
bind '"\C-j": "\C-atime {\C-e;}\C-m"'
```

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start a command, you'll get time information. Rebinding <kbd>Enter</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) is not recommended because the modified command will sometimes be syntactically incorrect.

See [How can the last command's wall time be put in the Bash prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862510/how-can-the-last-commands-wall-time-be-put-in-the-bash-prompt) and [Automatically timing every executed command and show in Bash prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176386/automatically-timing-every-executed-command-and-show-in-bash-prompt) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for other methods (note however that most only give the elapsed real time, not the CPU time).